# ¿Cuál es el origen de "leñe" como interjección?

Tags: etimología, expresiones, vulgaridades

Del Drae

> [leñe](https://dle.rae.es/?id=N8Yulrj)
>
> 1. interj. eufem. coloq. U. para denotar asombro, enfado o ira.

"Leñe" es un eufemismo, de acuerdo a la RAE. En [este hilo de Wordreference](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/le%C3%91e.1739644/) conjeturan que es de  "leche", pero no creo que "leche" sea una expresión tan fuerte como para necesitar eufemismo.

Respecto a su "origen etimológico" conjeturan (que no demuestran) que debido a esa "ñ" puede venir de "coño".

Aparte de eso no he conseguido encontrar mucho más.

¿Cuál es el origen (etimología) de "leñe" como interjección? ¿De qué término malsonante es un eufemismo?

Comment: No sé nada de *leñe*, pero cabe mencionar que en México si vas a la tiendita buscando un litro de leche, si te atiende una señora, no dirás *¿Tiene Ud. leche?* sino *¿Hay leche?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como usuario ávido que soy de dicha interjección me toca responder. Empezar diciendo que no lleva mucho tiempo en el diccionario, se ha recogido previamente solo en dos ediciones del *Academia Manual*, la de 1984 y la de 1989, antes de su inclusión definitiva en el DLE en 2001. Y eso que la expresión tiene más de un siglo, encuentro en el CORDE un caso de "¡Qué leñe!" en una obra de 1917.

Si echamos mano del *Fichero general* para ver qué dicen las fichas, veo que de momento algunas parecen atestiguar que es un eufemismo de *leche* (recogido así en el *Diccionario de argot* de 1980 de Víctor León y en la obra homónima de Juan Manuel Oliver de 1987). Sin embargo no se profundiza en el tema. Cierto es que *leche* no parece una palabra muy malsonante (bueno, según de qué *[leche](https://dle.rae.es/?id=N2tsDWF)* estemos hablando, ver acepciones marcadas como "vulgares"), pero sí es cierto que por la misma época en la que se dan los primeros casos se estilaban frases de este estilo:

> *—¿Por qué he sido tan envidioso, tan malo? ¿Qué hice para ser así? ¿Qué leche mamé?*
>
> Miguel de Unamuno, "Abel Sánchez, Una historia de pasión", 1917 (España).

Estas frases, tipo "la leche que mamaste" o "¿qué leche has mamado?", que hacen referencia a la madre de uno, son las que podrían haber sido objeto de eufemismo, trocando *leche* por *leñe*, tal vez influenciada por otras voces más vulgares como *coño*.

Por dar otra versión, en un libro titulado *El teatro de Antonio Gala*, de Fausto Díaz Padilla, [se dice](https://books.google.es/books?id=csBgRhbFJwEC&pg=PA96&lpg=PA96&dq=origen%20eufemismo%20le%C3%B1e&source=bl&ots=kk26SVDhVT&sig=ACfU3U0rq0MyTcMFSHPp-b5HEeATXhkJ4g&hl=es&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi4j76CytLiAhVBhRoKHarxA20Q6AEwDHoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=origen%20eufemismo%20le%C3%B1e&f=false) (hablando de las acepciones vulgares de *leche*):

> La interjección originaria *¡leche!* [del eufemismo *¡leñe!*] con valor obsceno, ya que se refería al semen masculino, se ha ido transformando en eufemística al perderse conciencia de este significado primitivo [...]. De ella se han formado las expresiones *"tener mala leche"* con el significado de "mal genio", y la variante humorística-eufemística *"mal café"* (de "café con leche"), que se trata de un origen metonímico, al igual que la muy reciente *"mal yogur"*.

Comment: `Como usuario ávido que soy de dicha interjección me toca responder` De hecho fue tu comentario en [Uno entre catorce mil](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3096/5481) lo que motivó esta pregunta. Curioso que "leñe" sea un eufemismo no de una palabra malsonante, si no de una _acepción_ de una palabra y que la propia palabra original "malsonante" se haya transformado en eufemismo "de sí misma" con el tiempo.